# MongoDB: How to group/transpose by array values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping, aggregation, transpose

I have a very simple collection with documents like this:

```js
{
  _id: 42,
  array: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
}
```

I'm looking for a query (aggregation) that can group by the array values and produce this:

```js
[
  {
    _id: "foo",
    matchingDocs: [
      {
        _id: 42,
        array: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
      },
      { ... }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) where `$$ROOT` recommends entire document that gets currently processed. Before you do that you need to add another array so that you'll get the original unwound array in the final result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: { arr: "$array" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$arr"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$arr",
            matchingDocs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "matchingDocs.arr": 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y5FwyyrGDaU)

Comment: That almost works, but it seems that `$$ROOT` contains the unwound document, like `array: "foo"`.

Comment: @nilskp correct, you have to add another one (temporary)